# How to use numy linalg lstsq to fit two datasets with same slope but different intercept?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, least-squares, data-fitting

I am trying to do weighted least-square fitting, and came across `numpy.linalg.lstsq`. I need to fit the weighted least squares. So, the following works:

```
# Generate some synthetic data from the model.
N = 50
x = np.sort(10 * np.random.rand(N))
yerr = 0.1 + 0.5 * np.random.rand(N)
y = 10.0 * x + 15
y += yerr * np.random.randn(N)
#do the fitting
err = 1/yerr**2
W = np.sqrt(np.diag(err))
x = x.flatten()
y = y.flatten()
A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
xw = np.dot(W,A)
yw = np.dot(W,y)
m, b = np.linalg.lstsq(xw, yw)[0]
```

which gives me the best-fit slope and intercept. Now, suppose I have two datasets with same slope but different intercepts? How would I do a joint fit such that I get best-fit slope plus two intercepts. I still need to have the weighted least square version. For an unweighted case, I found that the following works:

```
(m,b1,b2),_,_,_ = np.linalg.lstsq(np.stack([np.concatenate((x1,x2)),
                                        np.concatenate([np.ones(len(x1)),np.zeros(len(x2))]),
                                        np.concatenate([np.zeros(len(x1)),np.ones(len(x2))])]).T, 
                              np.concatenate((y1,y2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I rewrite your first approach as it can be written clearer in my opinion like this

```
weights = 1 / yerr
m, b = np.linalg.lstsq(np.c_[weights * x, weights], weights * y, rcond=None)[0]
```

To fit 2 datasets you can stack 2 arrays but make 0 some elements of matrix.

```
np.random.seed(12)
N = 3
x = np.sort(10 * np.random.rand(N))
yerr = 0.1 + 0.5 * np.random.rand(N)
y = 10.0 * x + 15
y += yerr * np.random.randn(N)

M = 2
x1 = np.sort(10 * np.random.rand(M))
yerr1 = 0.1 * 0.5 * np.random.rand(M)
y1 = 10.0 * x1 + 25
y1 += yerr1 * np.random.randn(M)
#do the fitting
weights = 1 / yerr
weights1 = 1 / yerr1
first_column = np.r_[weights * x, weights1 * x1]
second_column = np.r_[weights, [0] * x1.size]
third_column = np.r_[[0] * x.size, weights1]
a = np.c_[first_column, second_column, third_column]
print(a)
# [[  4.20211437   2.72576342   0.        ]
#  [ 24.54293941   9.32075195   0.        ]
#  [ 13.22997409   1.78771428   0.        ]
#  [126.37829241   0.          26.03711851]
#  [686.96961895   0.         124.44253391]]
c = np.r_[weights * y, weights1 * y1]
print(c)
# [  83.66073785  383.70595203  159.12058215 1914.59065915 9981.85549321]
m, b1, b2 = np.linalg.lstsq(a, c, rcond=None)[0]
print(m, b1, b2)
# 10.012202998026055 14.841412336510793 24.941219918240172
```

**EDIT**

If you want different slopes and one intercept you can do it this way. Probably it is better to grasp the general idea on the one slope 2 intercepts case. Take a look to array `a`: you construct it from weights as well as `c` so now it is unweighted problem. You try to find such `vector = [slope, intercept1, intercept2]` that `a @ vector = c` (as much as possible by minimizing sum of squares of differences). By putting zeros in `a` we make it separable: upper part of matrix `a` vary `slope` and `intercept1` and down part of `a` vary `slope` and `intercept2`. Similar to 2 slopes case with `vector = [slope1, slope2, intercept]`.

```
first_column = np.r_[weights * x, [0] * x1.size]
second_column = np.r_[[0] * x.size, weights1 * x1]
third_column = np.r_[weights, weights1]
```

Comment: But that would yield different intercept and slope for with and without zeros, right? As I understood it he would like to keep one fix.

Comment: @Joe I am not sure I fully understand your comment but it give one slope and 2 intercepts. When we generate `y` and `y1` we use 10, 15 and 25 as slope and 2 intercepts. And the last list of code show we get this values.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Will delete my answer.

Comment: One follow-up question: how would the code modify if I have two datasets with different slope but same intercept?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seems to work perfectly. One last question: Is there any way to get the standard uncertainties associated with the slope and intercept? The output seems to give the sum of residues only.

Comment: Wikipedia has equations for this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption

Comment: What if we want to do it for 3 datasets.. i.e. same slope but different intercepts. Sorry If I have missed the general idea behind this.